# how to calculate distance from a data frame compared to another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

let's say I have a data frame that consists of points :

df1:

```
x   y  z     label
1.1 2.1 3.1     2
4.1 5.1 6.1     1
7.1 8.1 9.1     0
```

and I also have another dataframe of points:

df2:

```
x  y  z   label
4  5  6    0
7  8  9    1
1  2  3    2
```

is there anyway to run through df one and see which point its the closest to inside of df2 and replace the label to the label of the point its closest to so..

the result I would like:

```
x   y    z  label
1.1 2.1 3.1   2
4.1 5.1 6.1   0
7.1 8.1 9.1   1
```

thanks for reading my question!

Comment: Define closest?  What is the equation?  Sum off difference on a row?

Comment: I mean just from a simple distance formula. so far instance point (1,2,3) being the closet to point (1.1,2.1,3.1)

Comment: BVOM, is this question answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of `distance` from `scipy`

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
df1['label']=df2.label.iloc[distance.cdist(df1.iloc[:,:-1], df2.iloc[:,:-1], metric='euclidean').argmin(1)].values
df1
Out[446]: 
     x    y    z  label
0  1.1  2.1  3.1      2
1  4.1  5.1  6.1      0
2  7.1  8.1  9.1      1
```

Comment: This may get computationally expensive. Might want to implement a kd-tree if you are doing this over two large arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using kd-trees, which may be much faster for large datasets.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from  sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
np.random.seed(0)
#since you have df1 and df2, you will want to convert the dfs to array here with
#X=df1['x'.'y','z'].to_numpy()
#Y=df2['x','y','z'].to_numpy()
X = np.random.random((10, 3))  # 10 points in 3 dimensions
Y = np.random.random((10, 3))
tree = KDTree(Y, leaf_size=2)  


#loop though the x array and find the closest point in y to each x  
#note the you can find as many as k nearest neighbors by this method
#though yours only calls for the k=1 case
dist, ind = tree.query(X, k=1) 

df1=pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['x','y','z']) 

#set the labels to the closest point to each neighbor
df1['label']=ind 

#this is cheesy, but it removes the list brackets 
#get rid of the following line if you want more than k=1 nearest neighbors
df1['label']=df1['label'].str.get(0).str.get(0)  
print(df1)

df1:
          x         y         z
0  0.548814  0.715189  0.602763
1  0.544883  0.423655  0.645894
2  0.437587  0.891773  0.963663
3  0.383442  0.791725  0.528895
4  0.568045  0.925597  0.071036
5  0.087129  0.020218  0.832620
6  0.778157  0.870012  0.978618
7  0.799159  0.461479  0.780529
8  0.118274  0.639921  0.143353
9  0.944669  0.521848  0.414662
df2:
          x         y         z
0  0.264556  0.774234  0.456150
1  0.568434  0.018790  0.617635
2  0.612096  0.616934  0.943748
3  0.681820  0.359508  0.437032
4  0.697631  0.060225  0.666767
5  0.670638  0.210383  0.128926
6  0.315428  0.363711  0.570197
7  0.438602  0.988374  0.102045
8  0.208877  0.161310  0.653108
9  0.253292  0.466311  0.244426

Out:
          x         y         z  label
0  0.548814  0.715189  0.602763      0
1  0.544883  0.423655  0.645894      6
2  0.437587  0.891773  0.963663      2
3  0.383442  0.791725  0.528895      0
4  0.568045  0.925597  0.071036      7
5  0.087129  0.020218  0.832620      8
6  0.778157  0.870012  0.978618      2
7  0.799159  0.461479  0.780529      2
8  0.118274  0.639921  0.143353      9
9  0.944669  0.521848  0.414662      3
```

Here is an image you can use to vet the results. The blue points are x points, and the orange are y points.
[image]

here is the code for the plot, using matplotlib version 3.0.2

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],X[:,2])
ax.scatter(Y[:,0],Y[:,1],Y[:,2])
for i in range(len(X)): #plot each point + it's index as text above
    ax.text(X[i,0],X[i,1],X[i,2],  '%s' % (str(i)), size=20, zorder=1, color='blue') 
for i in range(len(Y)): #plot each point + it's index as text above
    ax.text(Y[i,0],Y[i,1],Y[i,2],  '%s' % (str(i)), size=20, zorder=1, color='orange')
```

Comment: if I had points that are 11-d, would my case still be k=1? because I'm getting a 'query data dimension must match training data dimension'

Comment: Can you post some example + the error? k should be 1 if you only want the closest neighbor, and the 11-d doesn't effect that. It is simply how many neighbors you want to have returned for each single point. If you are feeding the query a single point, then you simple need to reshape it. Let's say I just want to look at the nearest neighbor of the first point in X. Then you reshape as follows "dist, ind = tree.query(X[0,:].reshape(1,-1), k=1)." kd-trees should work with any number of euclidean dimensions.

Comment: I just tested my code with 11-d space and it works, but you need to get rid of everything after this line "dist, ind = tree.query(X, k=1)" because the pandas and plotting parts of the code were written assuming 3d space. Obviously, you can't plot 11-d space in an easy to comprehend way, for example, though you could take cross sections.

Comment: when you say get rid of everything after that line, how do I still showcase the new labels then?

Comment: because if get rid of everything after that, I just have the tree of the data and that's all, sorry just trying to understand

Comment: I'dd add something for the 11-d case

Comment: I posted another answer for the generalized case. I think that this post answers your posted question better though, and if it were me I would accept this as the answer to the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ABS($df1 - $df2) as nearest, ...
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY nearest ASC
LIMIT 1
```

order them by 'X' index and then compare the $result arrays
this would look for the nearest number between the tables.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_abs.asp
the ABS function returns an absolute number so it will be a good solution as long as you have entire numbers on df2.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer addresses the question as asked, but the OP wanted a generalized solution for any number of dimensions, not just three.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from  sklearn.neighbors import KDTree


np.random.seed(0)
#since you have df1 and df2, you will want to convert the dfs to array here with
#X=df1['x'.'y','z'].to_numpy()
#Y=df2['x','y','z'.to_numpy()
n=11    #n=number of dimensions in your sample
X = np.random.random((10, n))  # 10 points in n dimensions
Y = np.random.random((10, n))
tree = KDTree(Y, leaf_size=2)  

indices=[]
#for i in range(len(X)):
    #loop though the x array and find the closest point in y to each x       
dist, ind = tree.query(X, k=1) 
#indices.append(ind)     
df1=pd.DataFrame(X)  
##set the labels to the closest point to each neighbor
df1['label']=ind
```

The result you want is now in df1, but you can't plot it easily, or interpret it without having a crazy brain. Proof of success based on 3d version also posted herein.